# Restrict folder rename cocoa

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, cocoa

[image: Applications folder]

Similar to Applications folder, i want to restrict user's of my application to rename some folders(created by my application).
So any cocoa/Objective-c/c++ API to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

What keeps `/Applications` from being renamed is that it sports an ACL (Access Control List) that denies delete. The actual ACL is:

```
group:everyone deny delete
```

Renaming something is tantamount to deleting its old name and adding its new name, so anything you can't delete you can't rename. In fact, that's the general principle—just make it un-deletable. That ACL is just one of many ways to do that.

Bear in mind that as long as the user owns the folder, they can remove the ACL and delete/rename to their heart's content. If they don't own it, how did you create it? `/Applications` is owned by root, and got that way because the OS X Installer (which has root privileges) created it that way. (Don't even consider going the same route. Requesting root privilege just to satisfy your sense of neatness is gauche.)

More to the point: why do you care if the user renames the folder? It's their computer. Either always look for it by the name you want it to have (so that renaming it is the same as deleting it in so far as your app cares), or better yet be considerate of your users and let them rename it to satisfy *their* sense of neatness. Keep an alias for it so you can continue to work with it under the new name.

Comment: That ACL is just one of many ways to do that, any way to make it un-deletable for that user(i know i cann't restrict admin/root)

Answer (score 0):

You can lock the folder . Please try with NSFileImmutable attribute of the folder with NSFileManager